# Fish shell can't change directory over a Webdav resource through Rclone

Tags: linux, fish, armbian, webdav, rclone

Fish can't `cd` into a folder on a Webdav remote directory through Rclone:

```bash
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type `help` for instructions on how to use fish
drive ) ls
Documents/  Music/           Videos/
Gem/        Misc/            Pictures/
drive ) cd Documents
cd: The directory “Documents” does not exist
drive ) sh
$ cd Documents
$ pwd
/mnt/drive/Documents
$ exit
drive )
```

Perhaps because it uses a wrapper around `cd`, maybe it is a bug, or instead I have to disable or rename the `cd` function, not sure how to address it.

Comment: What does `echo $FISH_VERSION` show? How about `echo $CDPATH`?

Comment: Hi, there you go: `echo $FISH_VERSION` returns: `3.1.2` ; while `echo $CDPATH` returns: `A BLANK LINE` ; thanks!

Comment: That fish version is quite old - the current version is 3.6.1, 3.1.2 is 31.1% of all commits ever made to fish behind. In particular this seems like it could be solved by https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/7586, which was added in fish 3.3.0. Go to https://fishshell.com/ for the official repositories to get a new fish version.

Comment: @faho I've just upgraded Armbian to bookworm, perhaps this will solve the issue!

Comment: Newer version now work!